# Merging ValueTable to geodatabase using ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, file-geodatabase, error-000840, value-table

I'm using a script a colleague put together a couple of years ago and there is an error when I try to run it. I know some Python but not much ArcPy. I've been fiddling with this for a couple of days now, read documentation on ESRI/ArcGIS website and on a couple of forums and I'm not sure where to turn.

Basically the scripts loops through a couple of .dgn (CAD) files and creates a geodatabase with all the info on the different layers. I'll only write the relevant lines of code. The error happens when trying to merge the the Table View with the geodatabase.

```py
type(out_lyr_prj) 
# <class 'str'>
# is it normal that it returns a string and not an arcgis object?
arcpy.Describe(out_lyr_prj)
# <geoprocessing describe data object object at 0x0000025C0ABB1DB0>
arcpy.Describe(out_lyr_prj).datasetType
# 'FeatureClass'
fields = [field.name for field in arcpy.ListFields(out_lyr_prj)]
# ['OID', 'Shape', 'Level', 'DocName', 'DocUpdate', 'DocId', 'Plan', 'No_Terrain']
d = [row for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(out_lyr_prj,fields)]
# [(1, (299363.48065021343, 5043349.720642636), 1, 'UP-216.dgn', datetime.datetime(2022, 2, 1, 14, 42, 22, 192000), 7.563238650671711e+18, 'UP-216', '216')]

gdb = 'C:\\some\\path\\gdb.gdb'
arcpy.CreateFileGDB_management(gdb)

vTab = arcpy.ValueTable()
vTab.addRow("in_memory/"+out_lyr_prj) # also tried "in_memory\\"
arcpy.Merge_management(vTab, os.path.join(gdb, "layer_name"))

# Traceback (most recent call last):
#   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
#   File "C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\Resources\ArcPy\arcpy\management.py", line 7064, in Merge
#     raise e
#   File "C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\Resources\ArcPy\arcpy\management.py", line 7061, in Merge
#     retval = convertArcObjectToPythonObject(gp.Merge_management(*gp_fixargs((inputs, output, # field_mappings, add_source), True)))
#   File "C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\Resources\ArcPy\arcpy\geoprocessing\_base.py", line 512, in # <lambda>
#     return lambda *args: val(*gp_fixargs(args, True))
# arcgisscripting.ExecuteError: Échec de l’exécution. Les paramètres ne sont pas valides.
# (Translation: Failed execution. Paramaters not valid.)
# ERROR 000840: The value is not a Vue tabulaire. (Vue tabulaire = Table View in french)
# Échec de l’exécution de (Merge).
# (Transation: Failed execution of (Merge))
```

Using Python 3.7 and Windows.

Comment: What do you see when you say `arcpy.Exists("in_memory/"+out_lyr_prj)`?

Comment: @fatih_dur: `arcpy.Exists("in_memory/"+out_lyr_prj)` = `True`

Comment: Another try, what happens if you change `vTab.addRow("in_memory/"+out_lyr_prj)` to `vTab.addRow(out_lyr_prj)`?

Comment: So it seems that this was built with a previous version of arcpy from ArcGIS Desktop which uses python 2. I'm using ArcGIS Pro which uses python 3 and currently arcpy 2.9. I can't seem to find much info on older arcpy versions so I'll try installing ArcGIS Desktop and running it again with the intended environment version.

Comment: @fatih_dur, I did try your suggestion with no effect. Thanks for your help!